# Gocron doesn't work when the day changes (GOLANG)

Tags: go, heroku, cron, scheduler

I made a scheduler with the hope that when the day changes this scheduler will run, but in fact after the day it changes it doesn't work. I use heroku as a server, does heroku not support this?

this is my scheduler

```
package scheduler

import (
    "github.com/go-co-op/gocron"
    "talkconnectv2/modules/smtp"
    "time"
)

type Scheduling interface {
    CronJobExporting() *gocron.Scheduler
}

type scheduler struct {
    Scheduler *gocron.Scheduler
}

func NewScheduler(sch *gocron.Scheduler) Scheduling {
    return &scheduler{
        Scheduler: sch,
    }
}

//need enhancement
func (sch *scheduler) CronJobExporting() *gocron.Scheduler {
    sch.Scheduler.Every(1).Days().Do(func() {
        testFormat()
    })
    sch.Scheduler.StartAsync()
    return sch.Scheduler
}

func testFormat() {
    smtp.NewEmailSmtp(
        smtp.EmailRequest{
            From:     "lalal@gmail.com",
            Password: "***********",
            To:       []string{"choirfilza@gmail.com"},
            Body: smtp.EmailMapping{
                EmailRegister: "testscheduler",
                Brand:         "testest",
                Tanggal:       time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"),
            },
        },
    ).SendEmail()
}
```

this the main

```
func main() {
    s := gocron.NewScheduler(time.UTC)
    ConfigRuntime()
    cache.Init()
    mongo.ConnectAll()
    scheduler.NewScheduler(s).CronJobExporting()
    StartGin()
    s.StartBlocking()

}
```

Comment: When you say "after the day change", you mean the time when the day changes in Indonesia right? I just wanna make sure what timezone you are referring to when you say "after the day change".

Comment: UTC, because the timezone in heroku is UTC

Comment: If this is a heroku free dyno, it will not work because the dyno stop after 30 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: no it's not free dynos,  i'm using profesional dynos

Answer (score 1):

[Heroku restarts your dyno every 24h](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts).

When `CronJobExporting` is called, it will wait 24 hour and run your `testFormat` function.

There's a high probability that your dyno is restarted before `gocron` has waited enough to run your task.

To run daily task on Heroku, you can use [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler).